C# CommunicationsClientBuilder not seeing a local certificate by its thumbprint
Executing the code outside of Azure (locally). The code is simple, replaced app id and name with foos:
            var mediaPlatformSettings = new MediaPlatformSettings()
            {
                MediaPlatformInstanceSettings = new MediaPlatformInstanceSettings()
                {
                    CertificateThumbprint = "52d85f98750cee735caba5d9e128c5ff64436d9a",
                    InstanceInternalPort = 80,
                    InstancePublicIPAddress = IPAddress.Any,
                    InstancePublicPort = 80,
                    ServiceFqdn = "mupse.pupse.com"
                },
                ApplicationId = "foo-id"
            };

            var builder = new CommunicationsClientBuilder(
                "foo",     // name
                "foo-id", // app id
                this.Logger);
            builder.SetMediaPlatformSettings(mediaPlatformSettings);

Getting error at the last line:
ArgumentException: CertificateThumbprint
Parameter name: Could not find a matching certificate for thumbprint 52d85f98750cee735caba5d9e128c5ff64436d9a

Certificate is self-signed, in pfx format, together with its private key. It is installed with MMC utility in Personal folder. It's rootCA is installed in Trusted Root Certificates folder; MMC doesn't report it as unsafe.
Relevant certificate properties, as per MMC:

Subject: CN = mupse.pupse.com
Subject Alternative Name: DNS Name=mupse.pupse.com
Thumbprint matches the one specified in MediaPlatformInstanceSettings

So, both CN and thumbprint matches between what is in store and what is in code.
Other things tried:

certificate without private key (pem file)
to install this certificate in Azure, both for app and in key-value
store
a valid non-self signed certificate, having correct CN, in Azure with
app
a non-related, existing certificate, taken from MMC
other similar manipulations, to no avail

Expected result: exception should not happen and media platform should be configured properly.

"It is installed with MMC utility in Personal folder" in Machine or User Certificates? Does the app user have rights to access the private key?

@Charlieface It started working once I installed them on computer account, was testing with my own all the time... should have tried that out. Thanks a lot.

Problem was solved by installing certificate on machine account. The program itself was launched by a users account, btw.
